# CloudKit не работают пуш-нотификации по подпискам CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate

Tags: objective-c, ios

Я формирую подписку один раз:

```
NSPredicate *truePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
CKSubscription *itemSubscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:CardAssetRecordType
                                                                    predicate:truePredicate
                                                               subscriptionID:[Utils GetUUID]
                                                                      options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate];


CKNotificationInfo *notification = [[CKNotificationInfo alloc] init];
notification.shouldSendContentAvailable = YES;

notification.alertLocalizationKey = @"";
notification.shouldBadge = NO;

itemSubscription.notificationInfo = notification;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.privateDatabase saveSubscription:itemSubscription completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        weakSelf.subscribedCardID = nil;
        if (iCloudLog)
        {
            NSLog(@"Subscribed with error : %@", error);
        }
    } else {
        if (iCloudLog)
        {
            NSLog(@"Subscribed to Cards : %@", subscription);
        }
        weakSelf.subscribedCardID = subscription.subscriptionID;
    }
    if (completionHandler)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler();
        });
    }
}];
```

И каждый раз когда я отправляю изменения по этому типу данных, на других устройствах я не получаю ни одного, никакого, совсем никакого сообщения. Регистрация пуш-нотификаций проходит без ошибок. Включен iCloud Sevices: CloudKit. Container заполнен Default Container. В Background Modes установлены Background fetch и Remote notifications. Данные в iCloud есть, изменения приходят. Но пуши не ходят совсем. Не понимаю почему такое происходит. Все сделано по инструкциям и примерам https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html, за исключением что у меня privateDatabase вместо publicDatabase. Кто-нибудь знает, как с этим бороться, потому что абсолютно этот же код работал примерно полмесяца назад исправно, все было отлично, ничего не менялось мной. И вдруг это перестает работать совсем.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7288 Это у Apple проблемы. Ждем исправлений.

Проблема на стороне Apple. Они обещают скоро выпустить обновление. Должно заработать в будущем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальное необходимое описание решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).